# ReleaseClient.GetReleaseDefinitionsAsync() call suddently started failing with JsonSerializationException

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

One of the customer asked us the following question.

I am using microsoft.visualstudio.services.release.client\15.130.0-preview to get a list of release definitions with triggers in my team project.

`await releaseHttpClient.GetReleaseDefinitionsAsync(project, null, ReleaseDefinitionExpands.Triggers);`

It was working so far but from last 1 month or so it started failing and I have started running into this error:

`System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 
Error converting value "tfsGit" to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.WebApi.PullRequestSystemType'. 
Path 'pullRequestConfiguration.codeRepositoryReference.systemType', 
line 1, position 238033. 
---> System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'tfsGit' was not found`

How should I come out of this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer we gave was: -

In last 1 month, [new release definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops) got added in your project which started using [pull request based trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-pull-request-builds?view=azure-devops) whose source code repository is tfsgit. Since your client library is more than a year old (15.130.0), it does not have those types.

So you should update your client library to latest and then it should work. You can find the latest client library [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Release.Client/).